# undefine process.env.HOST in nodejs

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

I just try to create .env file to use it for my first time
file dev.env

```
PORT=3000
USERNAME:root
PASSWORD:Password
DATABASE:mall
HOST:localhost   
DIALECT: mysql
URL:http://localhost:3000/
```

in package.json I did that

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "env-cmd -f ./app/config/dev.env nodemon server.js"
  },
```

I try to run the server by "npm run dev" but can't read process.env.HOST  so what did I miss in all of that

Comment: please use `=` not `:`.

Comment: Have you tried using `dotenv`?

Comment: @Hancel Lin
thank you very very much I spend about one week and try many things

Comment: @michael.grigoryan I don't think I need to use dontenv and problem solved after follow the Hancel Lin comment

Comment: Yeah, he is right. I didn't notice the `:`s. But yeah his answer is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to @Hancel Lin I just found the problem as mention in his comment "use = not :"